# C++ header unit importation syntax

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-modules

In the current C++ draft (august 2019), the grammar for a `pp-import` http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.import#nt:pp-import) allows for additional `pp-tokens` after the `header-name` or the `header-name-tokens`.

The current version of that section is the result of [P1703: "Recognizing Header Unit Imports Requires Full Preprocessing"](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1703r1.html). Before the changes caused by this proposal, the grammar still allowed for *preprocessing tokens* tokens after the `header-name` or the `header-name-tokens`, but in the form of a `pp-import-suffix`. (section [cpp.module] of [P1103](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1103r3.pdf)).

What is the reasoning behind allowing additional, unused *preprocessing tokens* in this context?

Thank you.

Comment: I found the following commit (https://github.com/cplusplus/modules-ts/commit/d2b044dd3f14af1fb926861a2f773e56fb439cc0) which introduced the `pp-decl-suffix` nonterminal, replacing `pp-attrs`. Maybe the remaining tokens should be used for attributes.

Comment: I was reading that part just two hours ago and also thinking this was a bug. Following the grammar's hypertext links, we end up having this http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#nt:preprocessing-token as possible extra tokens, which includes way too many ones for a valid import statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are there to allow for attributes.

The phase 7 (parsing and semantic analysis) grammar didn't change.  Attributes are still allowed on imports.  Previously the phase 4 (preprocessor) grammar tried to restrict more what was allowed as an import in order to enforce the rule that:

> A pp-import is only recognized when the sequence of tokens produced by phase 4 of translation up to the import token forms an import-seq, and the import token is not within the header-name-tokens or pp- import-suffix of another pp-import.

The new rules restrict it even further by not allowing more then one import per line, so this rule and its associated grammar are no longer needed.

Comment: So at phase 4, there is no check whether what follows the header-name is actually valid attribute syntax? e.g. at this phase, `import <foo> import + 123;` is valid?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read more about the import directive and I came to the following conclusion: a line containing `import pp-tokens;` is a preprocessing directive (as stated in http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp#1) and it should be first processed by the preprocessor (in case it matches the first two production rules of the `pp-import` non-terminal macro definitions should be imported). Next, the same line should be then *translated* (processed by the compiler), even if it matches the first two production rules or the third one, correct? [contd.]

Comment: However, being a preprocessing directive, it is deleted at the end of translation phase 4. Therefore it cannot be *translated*, right? Thank you again.

Comment: @JohanBoulé In the same way `nothing but a miracle can save me now C++` passes phase 4 because it contains valid tokens.  Whether it makes sense is checked later.

Comment: @MichaelSpencer I thought more about this and I think that because the `import` preprocessing token is replaced by the `import-keyword` preprocessing token, the `control-line` cannot be considered a `preprocessing directive` anymore, which means that it is not removed at the end of translation phase 4. Is this correct and if so, is this the only purpose of the `import-keyword` preprocessing token? Thank you.